# Left Side Menu opens when Right Side Menu is Clicked in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, xcode8, navigationbar

I'm using [ENSideMenu Library](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) for creating the menus in my navigation bar in Swift. I already created the left side menu of the navigation bar, but then when I created the right side. What happen is, when I click the right side button that contains the action for showing the right menu... the left side menu is shown instead. Here's my current implementation.

**RightSideNavigationController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let menu = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightMenuTableViewController") as! RightMenuTableViewController

    sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: menu, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition.right)
    sideMenu?.menuWidth = 200
    view.bringSubview(toFront: navigationBar)
}
```

**RightMenuTableViewController**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var destView: UIViewController!
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        destView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    } else {
          destView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

   }
   sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destView)

}
```

**SideNavigationController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let menu = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewController") as! MenuTableViewController
    sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: menu, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition.left)
    sideMenu?.menuWidth = 200
    view.bringSubview(toFront: navigationBar)
}
```

**MenuTableViewController**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var destinationViewController: UIViewController!



    if indexPath.section == 0{
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TopViewController") as! TopViewController
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
              destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MemberListViewController") as! MemberListViewController
        }
     }else {
         if indexPath.row == 0 {
             destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MemberRegisterViewController") as! MemberRegisterViewController

        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
              destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserRegistrationViewController") as! UserRegistrationViewController
        }

    }
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destinationViewController)

}
```

Comment: if you just change the position of sidenavigation controller to ENSideMenuPosition.right and then see does it come from right?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 yes, I'm aware that I can change the position of the menus. But, my problem is when I have two menus, only one menu shows up. Regardless, if I click the right or left menu.

Comment: Can you show the code for btn action for you right bar button?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I just called this toggleSideMenuView() in the action for the menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ENSideMenu` Library currently doesn't support 2 menus which uses the library in the same page. This is according to the issues posted in [ENSideMenu Library GitHub](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu/blob/master/Library/ENSideMenu.swift)